# jQuery Use Loop for Validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops

I have rather large form and along with PHP validation (ofc) I would like to use jQuery. I am a novice with jQuery, but after looking around I have some code working well. It is checking the length of a Text Box and will not allow submission if it is under a certain length. If the entry is lower the colour of the text box changes Red.

The problem I have is as the form is so large it is going to take a long time, and a lot of code to validate each and every box. I therefore wondered is there a way I can loop through all my variables rather than creating a function each time.

Here is what I have:

```
var form = $("#frmReferral");
var companyname = $("#frm_companyName");
var companynameInfo = $("#companyNameInfo");
var hrmanagername = $("#frm_hrManager");
var hrmanagernameInfo = $("#hrManagerInfo");

form.submit(function(){
    if(validateCompanyName() & validateHrmanagerName())
        return true
    else
        return false;
});
```

Validation Functions

```
function validateCompanyName(){
    // NOT valid
    if(companyname.val().length < 4){
        companyname.removeClass("complete");
        companyname.addClass("error");
        companynameInfo.text("Too Short. Please Enter Full Company Name.");
        companynameInfo.removeClass("complete");
        companynameInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //valid
    else{
        companyname.removeClass("error");
        companyname.addClass("complete");
        companynameInfo.text("Valid");
        companynameInfo.removeClass("error");
        companynameInfo.addClass("complete");
        return true;
    }
}

function validateHrmanagerName(){
    // NOT Valid
    if(hrmanagername.val().length < 4){
        hrmanagername.removeClass("complete");
        hrmanagername.addClass("error");
        hrmanagernameInfo.text("Too Short. Please Enter Full Name.");
        hrmanagernameInfo.removeClass("complete");
        hrmanagernameInfo.addClass("error");
        return false;
    }
    //valid
    else{
        hrmanagername.removeClass("error");
        hrmanagername.addClass("complete");
        hrmanagernameInfo.text("Valid");
        hrmanagernameInfo.removeClass("error");
        hrmanagernameInfo.addClass("complete");
        return true;
    }
}
```

As you can see for 50+ input boxes this is going to be getting huge. I thought maybe a loop would work but not sure which way to go about it. Possibly Array containing all the variables? Any help would be great.

Comment: use a validation framework like [jquery validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: Yup, agree with @ArunPJohny. Use a plugin. Its easy to use and getting help

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do and is a simplified version of how jQuery validator plugins work.

Instead of selecting individual inputs via id, you append an attribute `data-validation` in this case to indicate which fields to validate.

```
<form id='frmReferral'>
  <input type='text' name='company_name' data-validation='required' data-min-length='4'>
  <input type='text' name='company_info' data-validation='required' data-min-length='4'>
  <input type='text' name='hr_manager' data-validation='required' data-min-length='4'>
  <input type='text' name='hr_manager_info' data-validation='required' data-min-length='4'>
  <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then you write a little jQuery plugin to catch the submit event of the form, loop through all the elements selected by `$form.find('[data-validation]')` and execute a generic pass/fail validation function on them. Here's a quick version of what that plugin might look like:

```
$.fn.validate = function() {
  function pass($input) {
    $input.removeClass("error");
    $input.addClass("complete");
    $input.next('.error, .complete').remove();
    $input.after($('<p>', {
      class: 'complete',
      text: 'Valid'
    }));
  }

  function fail($input) {
    var formattedFieldName = $input.attr('name').split('_').join(' ');
    $input.removeClass("complete");
    $input.addClass("error");
    $input.next('.error, .complete').remove();
    $input.after($('<p>', {
      class: 'error',
      text: 'Too Short, Please Enter ' + formattedFieldName + '.'
    }));
  }

  function validateRequired($input) {
    var minLength = $input.data('min-length') || 1;
    return $input.val().length >= minLength;
  }

  return $(this).each(function(i, form) {
    var $form = $(form);
    var inputs = $form.find('[data-validation]');
    $form.submit(function(e) {
      inputs.each(function(i, input) {
        var $input = $(input);
        var validation = $input.data('validation');
        if (validation == 'required') {
          if (validateRequired($input)) {
            pass($input);
          }
          else {
            fail($input);
            e.preventDefault();
          }
        }
      })
    });
  });
}
```

Then you call the plugin like:

```
$(function() {
  $('#frmReferral').validate();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give them all a class for jQuery use through a single selector.  Then use your validation function to loop through and handle every case.

```
$(".validate").each(//do stuff);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    form.submit(function(){
        if(validateCompanyName() && validateHrmanagerName()) // Its logical AND not bitwise
            return true
        else
            return false;

You can do this.

var x = $("input[name^='test-form']").toArray();

for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
  validateCompanyName(x[i]);
 validateHrmanagerName(x[i]);
}
```

Comment: was there supposed to be an end for your submit( ? :D